# Mapping recursive structures in BizTalk

Tags: xslt, mapping, inline, biztalk

I have the following XML

```
     <response>
       <Contacts>
         <Contact>
           <Name>John Doe</Name>
           <Age>48</Age>
           <DOB>
             <Day>12</Day>
             <Month>6</Month>
             <Year>1964</Year>
           </DOB>
           <Contacts>
             <Contact>
                <Name>Jane Walsh</Name>
                <Age>30</Age>
                <DOB>
                  <Day>24</Day>
                  <Month>3</Month>
                  <Year>1983</Year>
                </DOB>
             </Contact>
             <Contact>
               <Name>Rob Marsh</Name>
               <Age>55</Age>
               <DOB>
                 <Day>1</Day>
                 <Month>Feb</Month>
                 <Year>1958</Year>
               </DOB>
             </Contact>
           </Contacts>
         </Contact>
       </Contacts>
    </response>
```

I am using the identity transform to copy the structure to the target.

```
    <xsl:template name = "testTemplate" match="/*[local-name()='response']/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="response"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Selectively mass copy some of the nodes without namespaces -->
    <xsl:template mode="copy-no-ns" match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

The XSL works in Altova XMLSpy and also when I test it with Visual Studio 2010 producing the desired output. But the BizTalk map produces empty nodes as below (removed other content which is copied correctly).

```
    <Contacts>
      <Contact>
        <Contacts>
          <Contact />
          <Contact />
        </Contacts>
      <Contact>
    </Contacts>
```

I don't see what is going on and how to fix this. Any suggestions? Thanks a ton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your obvious problem is here:**

> ```
>  <xsl:template name = "testTemplate" match="/*[local-name()='response']/*">
>       <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="response"/>
>  </xsl:template>
> ```

This template matches any child element of top element `response` (in this case just the element named `Contacts`.

Then it applies templates to all children of the matched `Contacts` element, that are named `response`. **However, the `Contacts` element has no child element named `response`**. At this point the transformation cannot produce any more output.

**The final result is just**:

```
<response>


</response>
```

**Here is the complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name = "testTemplate" match="/*[local-name()='response']/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="response"/>
 </xsl:template>

    <!-- Selectively mass copy some of the nodes without namespaces -->
 <xsl:template mode="copy-no-ns" match="*">
   <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<response>
    <Contacts>
        <Contact>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Age>48</Age>
            <DOB>
                <Day>12</Day>
                <Month>6</Month>
                <Year>1964</Year>
            </DOB>
            <Contacts>
                <Contact>
                    <Name>Jane Walsh</Name>
                    <Age>30</Age>
                    <DOB>
                        <Day>24</Day>
                        <Month>3</Month>
                        <Year>1983</Year>
                    </DOB>
                </Contact>
                <Contact>
                    <Name>Rob Marsh</Name>
                    <Age>55</Age>
                    <DOB>
                        <Day>1</Day>
                        <Month>Feb</Month>
                        <Year>1958</Year>
                    </DOB>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>
        </Contact>
    </Contacts>
</response>
```

**the result is as explained above:**

```
<response>


</response>
```

**Solution**:

**Just replace**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="response"/>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="node()"/>
```

**The complete transformation becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name = "testTemplate" match="/*[local-name()='response']/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

    <!-- Selectively mass copy some of the nodes without namespaces -->
 <xsl:template mode="copy-no-ns" match="*">
   <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-no-ns" select="node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the wanted result is produced**:

```
<response>
   <Contact>
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <Age>48</Age>
      <DOB>
         <Day>12</Day>
         <Month>6</Month>
         <Year>1964</Year>
      </DOB>
      <Contacts>
         <Contact>
            <Name>Jane Walsh</Name>
            <Age>30</Age>
            <DOB>
               <Day>24</Day>
               <Month>3</Month>
               <Year>1983</Year>
            </DOB>
         </Contact>
         <Contact>
            <Name>Rob Marsh</Name>
            <Age>55</Age>
            <DOB>
               <Day>1</Day>
               <Month>Feb</Month>
               <Year>1958</Year>
            </DOB>
         </Contact>
      </Contacts>
   </Contact>
</response>
```

**Do note**:

This transformation assumes that the elements have no attributes. If this assumption isn't true, the transformation produces wrong result on any XML document with attributes. It is possible to provide a correct and more generic transformation, but I believe that this is what you are asking for.